# How to Convert code to Obj-C?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c

How do I convert this to Objective-C?? Mainly this: `float *newH= new float[newD];`

What do I substitute new for in obj-c??

```
int newD = 100;

float *newH = new float[newD];

for(int i=0; i<newD; i++){
    newH[i] = 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: If you change your file from .m to .mm, you can use Objective C++, which allows you to directly integrate c++ into your program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objective-C is a true superset of C. In C, one uses malloc to allocate memory.

So,

```
float *newH = malloc( newD * sizeof( float) );
```

Of course, depending on what you are really doing, you may also want to investigate NSArray and NSNumber.

Note, that Objective-C++ is available as well and you can continue to use 'new' to allocate your memory.

Comment: if you use `calloc` instead of `malloc`, then the buffer will be zero'd out for you :)

Comment: Thank you all. That was a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of C++ code to port, you might be better off writing your app in Objective-C++. Then you can use your C++ code as is.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that Objective C++ is the way to go. However, if you absolutely want to stay within the spirit of Objective C (not straight C), here are the options:

- use an NSArray of NSNumber objects. This is slow - `float` boxing penalty applies.
- use a NSData as a allocation mechanism, cast [bytes] to float *. This is ugly, the way pointer typecasts are.